# amazon web service -EC2 linux vm has no graphics card or shared graphics

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, rdp

I am not sure if amazon simply does not offer graphics for linux vm instances or if its to do with configuration. But i recently setup a linux node on ec2 and i tried to setup rdp. I kept getting a blank screen but after much trial and error, went with bizspark and setup a linux node and to my surprise I see the bizspark linux node comes with a vga graphics card! while the amazon one does not!

Without a vga graphics card or builtin chipset its not possible to rdp in the linux node. 
So does amazon offer graphics card on linux vms or is it a simply a matter of configuration ?

edit: 
It is possible to have rdp even without a graphic card apparently. What I found out is one can install X2GO server on their ubuntu server and then just get the x2go client. No need for rdp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to get RDP working on EC2, take a look here:

http://michaelhallsmoore.com/blog/Desktop-Ubuntu-in-Amazon-EC2-The-Right-Way

or

http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/remote-graphical-linux-desktop-on-ec2/

You don't actually need a video card.

Comment: This link says ubuntu is not supported by nomachine https://www.nomachine.com/AR07K00676  what now ?

Comment: It says that it doesn't support the Unity desktop which was introduced in 12.04. You can use a different desktop such as gnome or KDE which is default in most other Linux distributions.

Comment: Ok so I installed KDE desktop and then installed  X2GO server. FREENX is no longer being maintained and in my case I am running ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty). Here is a link who wants remote connection on Ubuntu Server(14.04) http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:usage:start